# Outlier detection in linear combinations of variables

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, outliers

Suppose the student has a simple dataset composed of twelve variables labelled from V01 to V12. The linear combination of variables V01 to V07 define a variate called Meaning in Life. The linear combination of variables V08 to V12 define a variate called Life Satisfaction.

The student intends to run a simple linear regression where the variate Life Satisfaction will be regressed on Meaning in Life.

WHAT IS THE RIGHT WAY TO RUN OUTLIER ANALYSIS, given this scenario?

Should the student run an outlier detection procedure on each variate? How shall she consolidate the results if consequently, there will be two outlier detection outcomes (noting that a participant in the sample might be considered an outlier in one variate but not in the other)?

Should she run an outlier detection by combining all twelve variables? But what is the logic behind this approach?

Comment: Outlier detection to do what? Also, I’ve changed the title to reflect the topic you want to address.

Comment: An outlier detection to simplify the dataset of the student.

Comment: But to do what? You can simplify the data by transforming every observation to $0$. (Please don’t do that.)

Comment: Can I regress the variate of life satisfaction to the variate of the Meaning of life? Knowing that each variate will have different outliers? I would just like to remove the outliers in the data set because the outlier doesn't fit the model. Or should I just leave it be.

Comment: If your data don’t fit your model, that should be a hint that your model doesn’t represent reality.